# Index was outside the bounds of table C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to create an application where for each column in my datagridview, I get asked about the number of measure samples I want to do. Afterwards, it generates a maximum amount of samples, and makes some of them read-only depending on my table. The output should look somewhat like this:
[image]

Please note that the respectful measure samples for each of my rows are : 2,1,4,5, with 5 being the maximum in that example.

Here is the code that I came up with:

```cs
nombredemesures = new int[] { };
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[$"{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString() is "")
    {
        row.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        string result = Interaction.InputBox($"Valeur de :{row.Cells["ItemDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value?.ToString()}", "Title", "Default Text");
        nombredemesures = nombredemesures.Concat(new int[] { int.Parse(result) }).ToArray();
    }
}
int max = 0;
foreach (int value in nombredemesures)
{
    if (value > max)
        max = value;
}
int k = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) 
{ 
    dataGridView2.Columns.Add($"Test{i}", $"Donée de mesure{i}"); 
}
var resultt = from DataGridViewRow roww in dataGridView2.Rows select roww.Index;
foreach (var i in resultt)
{
    for (int j = max;j>(nombredemesures[k]); j--)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[$"Test{j}"].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get told that I'm outside the array boundaries. Does anyone understand why?

I tried changing the range of my loop, but it's useless because I haven't created a "measure sample0". Now I'm thinking about it being an issue with the array, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Where in your code is the exception thrown?

Comment: At the last index. Please wait while I update my post so you could see it.

Comment: While you are at it please fix the formatting of the code. Its hard to read the way it is now.

Comment: It seems someone fixed it for me. However, how does one change the formatting to make it more readable (even I have trouble reading through it XD).

Comment: Just like you would in your IDE? Primarily remove all the unnecessary whitespaces beyond  the ones for some proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

It uses zero-based indexes. You are using 1-based indexes.

You need to change

```
             for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
```

to

```
             for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
```

Comment: I changed it the way you told me, but it seems I am still outside the bounds of array.

Comment: That loop is used to create columns no access to something by index here so it does not matter if its 0-based or 1-based here.

Comment: I agree with @Ralf. However, I have no idea what the issue is (I usually am good with arrays).

Comment: Apologies, I should have looked at it more closely before answering.